# Flutter Getx Get.To(Directionality) do nothing in some cases

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation

I have 2 codes in 2 different screens in my Flutter project like this

```
                 GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => {
                      homeController.complexes[index].list
                          ? {
                              homeController.complexName.value =
                                  homeController.complexes[index].name,
                              Get.to(
                                () => Directionality(
                                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, child: ComplexListScreen()),
                              )
                            }
                          : {
                              homeController.complexName.value =
                                  homeController.complexes[index].name,
                              Get.to(
                                () => Directionality(
                                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, child: ComplexScreen()),
                              )
                            }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 180,
                      width: 125,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(homeController.complexes[index].image),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

and this

```
                  GestureDetector(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          complexListController.complexList[index].title,
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () => {
                        Get.to(
                          () => Directionality(textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, child: ComplexScreen()),
                        )
                      },
                    );
```

First code work whithout any problem and navigate to ComplexScreen but second code do nothing and if I remove Directionality work well .

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove => from onTap simple use

```
onTap:(){}
```

like this

```
onTap: (){
                          homeController.complexes[index].list
                              ? {
                                  homeController.complexName.value =
                                      homeController.complexes[index].name,
                                  Get.to(
                                    () => Directionality(
                                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, child: ComplexListScreen()),
                                  )
                                }
                              : {
                                  homeController.complexName.value =
                                      homeController.complexes[index].name,
                                  Get.to(
                                    () => Directionality(
                                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, child: ComplexScreen()),
                                  )
                                }
                        },
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer . solution 1 do not fix the problem . about solution 2 : I don't have problem with that code , I have problem with second code : onTap: () => {
                        Get.to(
                          () => Directionality(textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, child: ComplexScreen()),
                        )
                      },

Comment: please try without parsing argumets.

Comment: Can you explain or write any code plz

Comment: Directionality is your screen name?

Comment: No , Directionality is for changing direction to rtl . My screen name is ComplexScreen and Get.to work with Directionality in first code but do not work in 2nd . I need Directionality

Comment: you need to navigate into ComplexScreen like

Get.to(()=> ComplexScreen());

then why use Directionality?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241566/discussion-between-ravi-limbani-and-mm-sh).

Comment: I am in chat now